# Study results showed that the posttest scores got lower than the pretest scores, yet wilcoxon results show that there is significant difference

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

We had a study on the effectiveness of a learning intervention. We collected pre and post test scores and the results showed us that the students' scores got lower in posttest than the pretest. But when we analyzed these results using Wilcoxon signed rank test, it said that there is significant difference between the pre and posttest results. How is this possible? Is this even accurate?

Comment: You say yourself that posttest scores are lower than pretest scores. If they are, Wilcoxon should show a difference, as there is one. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I am just confused because posttest scores should be higher than the pretest yet with our results, posttest scores were lower.

Comment: we tested an intervention to a group of students so we are anticipating that they get higher scores in posttest to say that the intervention created significant impacts on them. But with the results, posttest results instead got lower and then the Wilcoxon revealed it had significant difference. May I ask, how will we explain this?

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps your intervention made things worse?

Comment: Apart from the possibility that the intervention made things worse, another possibility is a violation of the independence assumption. Did your students communicate with each other, maybe did exam preparation together etc.?

Comment: @Anne in your signed rank test calculations, are you using the right alternate hypothesis? Your research question suggests a greater (one-sided) alternate hypothesis, while your results suggest you might be using a two-sided alternate hypothesis.